# Hugo. Is there a way to generate a valid URL from asciidoc link:file.adoc[title]

Tags: hugo, asciidoc, asciidoctor, cross-reference

I have a hugo project structure like this:

```
content/
   _index.md
   a.adoc
   b.adoc
```

There is a cross-reference to the a.doc in b.adoc

```
link:a.adoc[The page "a"]
```

Hugo renders the link to the URL like this: http://my-site.com/a.doc

But this page doesn't exist and i get 404 when going to the URL.
The valid URL is http://my-site.com/a

Is there a way for generating a valid URL like above?
There may be a solution similar to [markdown-render-hooks](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup#markdown-render-hooks)?

```
layout
  _default
    _markup
       render-link.html
```

Comment: The link is rendered by Asciidoctor, not Hugo. The link macro is rendered "as is". You would have more control if it was an xref macro.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you! xref works!
I found the answer about xref: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-valid-url-from-asciidoc-link-file-adoc-title/37283/2